# Installing 14.01 on to a spare drive in PC

Tags: dual-boot

I have a PC with 3 Hard-drives.
I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.01 onto one of them.
I have tried now 3 times and came nowhere.
I used the “Something else” option.
After all the installation procedures, I like to reboot the PC , 
I have to use the BIOS switching to try and just get an ERROR = [ No such partition see grub rescue ] ?
I am also than unable to see the “Ubuntu drive” with windows7. Just gone !
If I reboot with Ubuntu live CD than I can see all 3 drives ?
Please help, what do I make wrong.

I have retyped all the info from the Ubuntu Installation screen .

The “tick” is greyed out and I cannot get rid of it.

I have to use Win7 Disk Management to re-format the drive and make a swap partition and than I am back at square 1.

Copied from photo taken of the screen.
Device      Type Mount point Format? Size  Used       System
/dev/sda
  /dev////sda1  ntfs            60037 MB 80576 MB  Microsoft Windows XP Professional
/dev/sdb
  /dev/sdb1 ext4   /  tick      80011 MB    92 MB
  /dev/sdb2     swap                9 MB     0 MB
/dev/sdc
  /dev/sdc1 ntfs                  104 MB    71 MB   Windows 7 (Loader)
  /dev/sdc2 ntfs           159933 MB 58695 MB

Device for boot loader installation:
 /dev/sdb1

Answer (score 0):

Note that the bootloader should be on the HDD itself, and not a partition.
You can try to re-install the system noting this important infomation, should it fail,
I think the easiest method is to unplug the other HDDs and install ubuntu as normal.

You can then plug in the other HDDs and then use the BIOSs boot menu to select when to boot from the ubuntu HDD. you can also use the ubuntu disk in order to boot the other OSs, when you've booted inside ubuntu with both HDDs, just run `sudo update-grub2` in order to add the new entries. (this command will actually run after you install all of the updates as there will be a kernel upgrade available which will trigger grub to update).

Please note, most BIOSs are "smart" and will remove the missing devices from the default boot if they're not available during just one boot.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Partitions are not visible in windows its normal. You should use ext explorer software in windows to view Ubuntu Partitions.

Comming to your grub problem where did you install the grub boot loader during installation
[image]

In the above pic during installation at "Device for boot loader installation" you should carefully select your hard drive on which you are installing Ubuntu like /dev/sdb (and not /dev/sdb1 not numbered partitions select the whole hard disk) and install

I hope that helps